# Is nestjs caching or something

Tags: nestjs

I have a controller FooController with 3 routes

```
@Post
@Get
@Get('/:id')
```

Even if I restart server, my controller isn't updated.

I edit something, it's updated after like 50 restarts, it look like nestjs is hard caching something but I don't find anything.

10 minuts ago:

```
throw new HttpException({ message: 'Failed to get surveys' }, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

5 minuts ago:

```
throw new HttpException({ error: 'test, message: 'Failed to get surveys' }, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

I still get only `{ message }` in my response.

I remove @Get('/id') and restart again and again server, my front still can make @Get('/id') request and it return the survey, wtf is this ?

I need to spam restart till I get error, it's so boring!

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know anything about nestjs. But are there any logs written?

Comment: There are nest logs, console.log do nothing with nest...

Comment: How are you re-starting the server? Are you rebuilding the Typescript to JavaScript?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes, I've tryed to delete /dist and it works. But it is a very bad solution to delete /dist everytime I guess

Comment: @PierreD that doesn't answer my question. **How** are you re-starting the server? What is your command you are passing via npm?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Sry, I run nest start --watch

Comment: Interesting. The only "caching" nest could be doing would be what typescript does with incremental compilation and I've never seen that be an issue in the past. What OS are you running on with what versions of common and core and the cli?